# How to get coordinate center maps on android and showing in textview?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I'm trying to get coordinate from center of maps and showing in textview, and When I scroll map, coordinate changed.

**Here is my Kotlin code:**

```
class ActivityMapsNewPlotBng :
        AppCompatActivity(),
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener{
...
override fun onLocationChanged(newLocation: Location?) {
        val latLng = LatLng(newLocation!!.latitude, newLocation.longitude)
        mMapsNPlotBng!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
        mMapsNPlotBng!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18f))
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this)
        }

    }

    override fun onCameraIdle() {
        val centerPos : LatLng = mMapsNPlotBng.cameraPosition.target
        tv_nplotbng_lat.setText("" + centerPos.latitude)
        tv_nplotbng_long.setText("" + centerPos.longitude)
    }
}
```

This code didn't work, please help me.
Thank's for attention.

Comment: obviously, coordinates of center will change if you scroll : |

Comment: Yes, i want to showing that coordinate in textview. But, my code did'nt work

Answer (score 1):

In onCameraIdle method

```
LatLng latLng = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.getCenter();
```

Comment: projection is heavy operation